# What are series and bucket in InfluxDb

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2

While trying to understand different concepts of InfluxDb I came across [this](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/concepts/crosswalk/) documentation, where there is a comparision of terms with SQL database.

> An InfluxDB measurement is similar to an SQL database table.
>   InfluxDB tags are like indexed columns in an SQL database.
>    InfluxDB fields are
>   like unindexed columns in an SQL database.
>    InfluxDB points are similar
>   to SQL rows.

But there are couple of other terminology which I came across, which I could not clearly understand and wondering if there is an SQL equivalent for that.

**Series**
**Bucket**

From what I understand from the documentation

> series is the collection of data that share a retention policy,
>   measurement, and tag set.

Does this mean a series is a subset of data in a database table? Or is it like database views ?
 I could not see any documentation explaining buckets. I guess this is a new concept in 2.0 release

Can someone please clarify these two concepts.

Comment: As I understand it, while a measurement refers to the concept of storage, a series is the actual data stored in said measurement.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have summarized my understanding below:

- A **bucket** is named location with retention policy where time-series data is stored.
- A **series** is a logical grouping of data defined by shared measurement, tag and field.
- A **measurement** is similar to an SQL database table.
- A **tag** is similar to indexed columns in an SQL database.
- A **field** is similar to unindexed columns in an SQL database.
- A **point** is similar to SQL row.

For example, a SQL table `workdone`:

| **`Email`** | **`Status`** | **`time`** | **`Completed`** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lorr@influxdb.com | start | 1636775801000000000 | 76 |
| lorr@influxdb.com | finish | 1636775868000000000 | 120 |
| marv@influxdb.com | start | 1636775801000000000 | 0 |
| marv@influxdb.com | finish | 1636775868000000000 | 20 |
| cliff@influxdb.com | start | 1636775801000000000 | 54 |
| cliff@influxdb.com | finish | 1636775868000000000 | 56 |

The columns `Email` and `Status` are indexed.

Hence:

- Measurement: `workdone`
- Tags: `Email`, `Status`
- Field: `Completed`
- Series (Cardinality = 3 x 2 = 6):

  1. Measurement: `workdone`; Tags: `Email`: `lorr@influxdb.com`, `Status`: `start`;  Field: `Completed`
  2. Measurement: `workdone`; Tags: `Email`: `lorr@influxdb.com`, `Status`: `finish`; Field: `Completed`
  3. Measurement: `workdone`; Tags: `Email`: `marv@influxdb.com`, `Status`: `start`; Field: `Completed`
  4. Measurement: `workdone`; Tags: `Email`: `marv@influxdb.com`, `Status`: `finish`; Field: `Completed`
  5. Measurement: `workdone`; Tags: `Email`: `cliff@influxdb.com`, `Status`: `start`; Field: `Completed`
  6. Measurement: `workdone`; Tags: `Email`: `cliff@influxdb.com`, `Status`: `finish`; Field: `Completed`

Splitting a logical series across multiple buckets may not improve performance but may complicate flux query as need to include multiple buckets.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [InfluxDB glossary](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/concepts/glossary/):

> ### Bucket
>
> A bucket is a named location where time-series data is stored in InfluxDB 2.0. In InfluxDB 1.8+, each combination of a
> database and a retention policy (database/retention-policy) represents
> a bucket. Use the [InfluxDB 2.0 API compatibility endpoints](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/tools/api/#influxdb-2-0-api-compatibility-endpoints) included
> with InfluxDB 1.8+ to interact with buckets.

> ### Series
>
> A logical grouping of data defined by shared measurement, tag
> set, and field key.

Answer (score 4):

The InfluxDb document that you link to has an example of what a **Series** is, even if they don't label it as such. In InfluxDb, you can think of each combination of measurement and tags as being in it's own "table". The documentation splits it like this.

This table in SQL:

```
+---------+---------+---------------------+--------------+
| park_id | planet  | time                | #_foodships  |
+---------+---------+---------------------+--------------+
|       1 | Earth   | 1429185600000000000 |            0 |
|       2 | Saturn  | 1429185601000000000 |            3 |
+---------+---------+---------------------+--------------+
```

Becomes these two Series in InfluxDb:

```
name: foodships
tags: park_id=1, planet=Earth

----

name: foodships
tags: park_id=2, planet=Saturn

...etc...
```

This has implications when you query for the data, and is also the reason why [the recommendation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/concepts/schema_and_data_layout/#avoid-too-many-series) is that you don't have `tag` values with high cardinality. For example, if you had a tag of `temperature` (especially if it was a precise to multiple decimal points) that InfluxDb would be creating a "table" for each potential combination of `tag` values.

A **Bucket** is much easier to understand. It's just a [combination of a database with a retention policy](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/concepts/glossary/#bucket). In previous versions of InfluxDb these were separate concepts which have now been combined.

Comment: How do you create a database inside a bucket in cloud?

Comment: Based on the documentation (https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/concepts/glossary/#series) series "are defined by their shared measurement, tag set, and field key".

However fields are indexed, only tags are not. So, shouldn't it be that you can have many series, but separated not based on tags but fields?

Comment: You've got it backwards @nocibambi - tags are indexed, not fields. See the [tag glossary item](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/concepts/glossary/#tag). In the above example, `park_id` and `planet` are tags and would be indexed for performance. The field is `#_foodships` and represents the value of the measurement which potentially has a high cardinality.

Comment: Yes, you are right, my bad. Thanks for the correction!